# Can you replace a shower handle without replacing the valve?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

My wife and I have been slowly remodeling our out with the linoleum and laminate, in with tile and granite. Part of that has been slowly replacing the fixtures with those of a different finish -- including the shower head and handle. I've found set on amazon that I believe would look nice, but it comes with it's own valve body. I'm not keen on ripping out the wall to replace a functioning existing valve body; can I just use the handle and facia off of the new handle, while keeping the body from the old handle?

Comment: Probably not. Post a picture of your current setup and the new parts you wish to use. Unless the two are same brand and style they most likely will not interchange.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what valve you have. What you're looking for is called a shower trim kit. When homes are built and the plumbing is done the shower valve is installed. Later the customer/homeowner picks out a trim kit which is the plate, handle and shower head. Depending on what valve you have there may be a good selection of trim kits or none at all. There is a bit of savings with the trim kit because you're not paying for a valve.